# Getting npm install error

Tags: node.js, npm

When i am trying npm install i am getting following error. Please suggest me what could be the possible problem and solution for this problem.

```
npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNR
EFUSED
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "d:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "d:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd d:\Asgard_Odin\odin\asgard-framework
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     d:\Asgard_Odin\odin\asgard-framework\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Hum, did you look at the error message ? Is it a proxy problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This error could be caused by various reasons:

- The npm servers having some troubles. Try a mirrow, for example: [npmjs.eu](http://npmjs.eu/)
- You are behind a firewall? Try to [set up a proxy](http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy) for npm.